# convert to UUID in ThingsBoard

Tags: postgresql, thingsboard

I just upgraded from Thingsboard 2.4 to 3.0, and also from postgresql 9.6 to 12.
I have been working on retrieving data from Postgre while getting data from a ts_kv table using a key without hyphens values.
An entity_id field of a ts_kv table was like a '1e81629b3d597b0b9dd7d78e05760aa' in postgresql 9.6. The value has no hypyens. But the entity_id field of a ts_kv table was changed like a 'b3d597b0-1629-11e8-b9dd-7d78e05760aa' in postgre 12. All of the id field are like '1e81629b3d597b0b9dd7d78e05760aa' except ts_kv table. A value with hyphens might be UUID.

I can get the id field's values without hyphens from the device table, and then I would like to select some key values from the ts_kv table.

Can I convert a value without hyphens to UUID?
And are there some methods to retrieve data from ThingsBoard database?

Thanks

Comment: The hyphens are always generated by Postgres as display of a uuid, they are not actually present and on the input side with or without hyphens  are the same, either format may be used. If you need to display without hyphens then cast it to text and use the replace function to remove them.  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ccf6ffef5115ead7dab13d2f102001af) demonstrating both.

Comment: One table has   '8ee0a190-b298-11e9-a151-0f81c8b4f14e', but the others have '1e9b2988ee0a190a1510f81c8b4f14e ' for the same device. I guess  they might have some permutation each other.

Comment: I would doubt there is any  permutation or any other relationship between them. I would think it is just the same device assigned different keys.  I assume these entity_id columns are generated PK. Keep in mind that the purpose of generated keys is strictly to keep rows unique within a table. This actually has nothing to do with identifying them for *business purposes*. Perhaps a  unique key, or at least a non-unique index, on the device in each table; write your query to look up by device.

Comment: Thank you, Belayer. Unfortunately after I  get the id, '1e9b2988ee0a190a1510f81c8b4f14e ', of a device, I have to get some values from a table using the id, '8ee0a190-b298-11e9-a151-0f81c8b4f14e'. Therefore, I have to transform from '1e9b2988ee0a190a1510f81c8b4f14e ' to '8ee0a190-b298-11e9-a151-0f81c8b4f14e'.

Comment: What means the PK ?

Comment: PK => Primary Key

Answer (score 1):

We have used weird representation of UUID in 2.x to maintain compatibility between our Cassandra and Postgresql API and allow sorting of entities by created time. It was a bad design and that is why in 3.x we replaced weird representation of UUID with normal representation and also added created_time. See the conversion function:

https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/35feb2fea43bbb8d39071af63fa6426f25502dd5/dao/src/main/resources/sql/schema-entities.sql#L344